# jQuery - show some element on 2 seconds focus

Tags: jquery, focus

is it possible to show some element on focus 2 seconds on some other element?

```
$("#someDiv").focus(function(){
  // 2 seconds focus??
  $("#someOtherDiv").show();
});
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setTimeout on focus and cleatTimeout on blur.

```
var timer;
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#TextBox").focus(function () {
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#ShowMe").show();
        }, 2000);
    });

    $("#TextBox").blur(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#ShowMe").hide();
    });
});
```

here: [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aycjf5u5/)

Answer (score 0):

is it fine do that by "click" event?
if so check this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#someDiv').click(function(){
    $('#someOtherDiv').show(300).delay(2000).hide(300);
});});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rbkLrhdq/1/)